# Merge/Join two List<Tuple>

Tags: java, list, merge, tuples

I have two Lists as below:

```
List<Tuple> tuple1, List<Tuple> tuple2
```

Where each Tuple is having two values : ID, COUNT

Now I have to merge tuple1 and tuple2 and store them List

ClassA is:

```
public class ClassA{
     private int id; //matches tuple1.ID / tuple2.ID
     private int count1; //matches tuple1.COUNT
     private int count2; //matched tuple2.COUNT
.....
}
```

Can you guys help me to merge this with Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put items from first ``List`` in a ``Map`` (id, count), iterate through second ``List``, get count from ``Map``, create new ``ClassA`` instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no requirement of duplicates not being allowed the easiest would be:

```
List<Tuple> combined = new ArrayList<>(tuple1);
combined.addAll(tuple2);
```

Comment: As far as I understood, he wants an SQL-like join. If not, this is the correct answer in contrast to my comment above of course.

Comment: Yes I have, until he clarifies it further I cannot guess anymore at his intent and will assume his problem is simple requiring a simple solution.

Comment: I want entries of Tuple1 and Tuple2 should be mapped with classA objects where classA.id = Tuple1.get(0) / Tuple2.get(0) , classA.count1 = Tuple1.get(1) and classA.count2 = Tuple2.get(1)